# Galera 10 cluster node dropping queries

Tags: mariadb, galera

We are encountering an error on Node 1 of a 5-node cluster.  Queries to Node 1 seem to succeed from a client perspective but are failing to insert.  We are seeing a lot of autoinc errors even though autoinc shouldn't be involved in the update queries.  Also, this seems to cause performance issues until a higher-priority transaction occurs knocking the node offline to perform transaction replay.  Below are some of the entries in `error.log` with debugging on and a walkthrough of setup.  We are at a loss for how to troubleshoot further.

The only way to cause transactions to continue is for all the clients to drop and rebuild connection pool.

Some details of the setup:

- 5 Nodes all acting as a master to their local server
- All connected via WAN
- Node 1 also has outside SQL connections for website access
- Each node is running inside of docker on the physical machine

Here are some of the errors:

```
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: DUPKEY error for autoinc
THD 5041, value 133622, off 2 inc 5
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: retrying insert: INSERT INTO `server_live` (server_id, performance_30, performance_120, performance_300, performance_600, players_online, staff_online, staff_last_seen, uptime, worlds_loaded, chunks_loaded, entities_loaded, tileEntities_loaded) VALUES (79, 100, 100, 99, 99, 2, '{}', staff_last_seen, 15568, 13, 789, 384, 1101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE performance_30 = 100, performance_120 = 100, performance_300 = 99, performance_600 = 99, players_online = 2, staff_online = '{}', staff_last_seen = staff_last_seen, uptime = 15568, worlds_loaded = 13, chunks_loaded = 789, entities_loaded = 384, tileEntities_loaded = 1101
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: innobase_commit, abort INSERT INTO `server_live` (server_id, performance_30, performance_120, performance_300, performance_600, players_online, staff_online, staff_last_seen, uptime, worlds_loaded, chunks_loaded, entities_loaded, tileEntities_loaded) VALUES (79, 100, 100, 99, 99, 2, '{}', staff_last_seen, 15568, 13, 789, 384, 1101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE performance_30 = 100, performance_120 = 100, performance_300 = 99, performance_600 = 99, players_online = 2, staff_online = '{}', staff_last_seen = staff_last_seen, uptime = 15568, worlds_loaded = 13, chunks_loaded = 789, entities_loaded = 384, tileEntities_loaded = 1101
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: cleanup transaction for LOCAL_STATE: INSERT INTO `server_live` (server_id, performance_30, performance_120, performance_300, performance_600, players_online, staff_online, staff_last_seen, uptime, worlds_loaded, chunks_loaded, entities_loaded, tileEntities_loaded) VALUES (79, 100, 100, 99, 99, 2, '{}', staff_last_seen, 15568, 13, 789, 384, 1101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE performance_30 = 100, performance_120 = 100, performance_300 = 99, performance_600 = 99, players_online = 2, staff_online = '{}', staff_last_seen = staff_last_seen, uptime = 15568, worlds_loaded = 13, chunks_loaded = 789, entities_loaded = 384, tileEntities_loaded = 1101
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: wsrep retrying AC query: INSERT INTO `server_live` (server_id, performance_30, performance_120, performance_300, performance_600, players_online, staff_online, staff_last_seen, uptime, worlds_loaded, chunks_loaded, entities_loaded, tileEntities_loaded) VALUES (79, 100, 100, 99, 99, 2, '{}', staff_last_seen, 15568, 13, 789, 384, 1101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE performance_30 = 100, performance_120 = 100, performance_300 = 99, performance_600 = 99, players_online = 2, staff_online = '{}', staff_last_seen = staff_last_seen, uptime = 15568, worlds_loaded = 13, chunks_loaded = 789, entities_loaded = 384, tileEntities_loaded = 1101
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: DUPKEY error for autoinc
THD 5041, value 133627, off 2 inc 5
150703  5:56:27 [Note] WSREP: releasing retry_query: conf 0 sent 0 kill 0  errno 0 SQL INSERT INTO `server_live` (server_id, performance_30, performance_120, performance_300, performance_600, players_online, staff_online, staff_last_seen, uptime, worlds_loaded, chunks_loaded, entities_loaded, tileEntities_loaded) VALUES (79, 100, 100, 99, 99, 2, '{}', staff_last_seen, 15568, 13, 789, 384, 1101) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE performance_30 = 100, performance_120 = 100, performance_300 = 99, performance_600 = 99, players_online = 2, staff_online = '{}', staff_last_seen = staff_last_seen, uptime = 15568, worlds_loaded = 13, chunks_loaded = 789, entities_loaded = 384, tileEntities_loaded = 1101
```

#### Our config

```
[MYSQLD]
datadir=/data
log-error=/data/error.log
query_cache_size=0
binlog_format=ROW
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
port=3304
innodb_buffer_pool_size=2048M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_read_io_threads=4
innodb_write_io_threads=4
innodb_io_capacity=200
innodb_doublewrite=1
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=64
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
default_storage_engine=innodb

binlog_format=ROW
key_buffer_size = 24M
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 512M
skip_name_resolve
memlock=0
sysdate_is_now=1
max_connections=512
thread_cache_size=512
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
table_open_cache=1024
lower_case_table_names=0
wait_timeout = 28800
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_provider_options="gcache.size=2048M; evs.keepalive_period=PT3S;     evs.inactive_check_period=PT10S; evs.suspect_timeout=PT30S; evs.inactive_timeout=PT1M; evs.install_timeout=PT1M; evs.send_window=1024; evs.user_send_window=512;"
wsrep_cluster_name="<removed>"
wsrep_cluster_address="<removed>"
wsrep_slave_threads=4
wsrep_certify_nonPK=1
wsrep_max_ws_rows=131072
wsrep_max_ws_size=1073741824
wsrep_debug=1
wsrep_convert_LOCK_to_trx=0
wsrep_retry_autocommit=10
wsrep_auto_increment_control=1
wsrep_replicate_myisam=1
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround=1
wsrep_causal_reads=0
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_log_conflicts=1
```

***UPDATE:***
Per request for comments:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE server_live;
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| server_live | CREATE TABLE `server_live` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `performance_30` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `performance_120` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `performance_300` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `performance_600` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `players_online` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `staff_online` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}',
  `staff_last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `uptime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `worlds_loaded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chunks_loaded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entities_loaded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tileEntities_loaded` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `server_id_2` (`server_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `server_live_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`server_id`) REFERENCES `server` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=720312 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 5     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 3     |
| autocommit               | ON    |
| automatic_sp_privileges  | ON    |
+--------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto%';` -- verify that auto_increment_increment is 5 on all nodes an that auto_increment_offset is different on all nodes.

Comment: All 5 nodes show auto_increment_increment as 5
The only difference from the below output is that auto_increment_offset is different on every server with servers counting 1,2,3,4,5
Please see OP for results of command from 1 node

Comment: Also to note is that from an application perspective the queries never show as failed.  The application indicates that queries are returning OK when they aren't really.  It is not fixed unless you restart the application in which case it returns to normal.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to send to MariaDB and/or Galera (codership).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic.  Try https://dba.stackexchange.com/.